Tally Auto Column Report in XML
I have a TDL that shows a report of P&L of cost centres. By default it shows just the P&L and total amount.
Using auto column, it gives option to see at column level (each column is a cost centre).
I have an xml code through which I am able to get the default view of the report but struggling to extract the columnar view by cost centre.
Below is the xml code
<HEADER>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<EXPORTDATA>
<REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>TSPL FFE CostCentre P AndL</REPORTNAME>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVFROMDATE>20230401</SVFROMDATE>
<SVTODATE>20240331</SVTODATE>
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:ASCII</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
<EXPLODEALLLEVELS>Yes</EXPLODEALLLEVELS>
<SVCOLUMNTYPE>$$SysName:AllItems</SVCOLUMNTYPE>
<DSPREPEATCOLLECTION>List Of Cost Centres</DSPREPEATCOLLECTION>
<DOSETAUTOCOLUMN>Yes</DOSETAUTOCOLUMN>
<SVCOLUMNTYPE>$$SysName:AllItems</SVCOLUMNTYPE>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</REQUESTDESC>
</EXPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>'''

I am able to get the default view of the report but struggling to extract the columnar view by cost centre.
